# ASP.NET Core DPAPI PersistKeyToFileSystem encrypting the key

Tags: asp.net-core, dpapi

I am using ASP.NET Core DPAPI. The key in use is currently unprotected.
I see in the docs an example that shows the key encrypted, but I can't figure out what is the api setting for that.

I am using the following:

```
services
.AddDataProtection()
.SetApplicationName("MyApp")
.SetDefaultKeyLifetime(TimeSpan.FromDays(3))
.PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo("C:\MyDir"));
```

Below is an excerpt of the generated xml file:

```
    <descriptor>
      <encryption algorithm="AES_256_CBC" />
      <validation algorithm="HMACSHA256" />
      <masterKey p4:requiresEncryption="true" xmlns:p4="http://schemas.asp.net/2015/03/dataProtection">
        <!-- Warning: the key below is in an unencrypted form. -->
        <value>123345689...0987654321</value>
      </masterKey>
    </descriptor>
  </descriptor>
```

I want the disk persisted key to be encrypted as well. How do I achieve this ?

This [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-storage-format?view=aspnetcore-3.1#the-encryptedsecret-element) shows an example with an encrypted key.
What are the api method calls required to generate the xml key file with an encrypted key?

Answer (score 2):

There are currently three methods available to encrypt the key before it's persisted to storage.

- [ProtectKeysWithCertificate](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection.dataprotectionbuilderextensions.protectkeyswithcertificate?view=aspnetcore-3.1)
- [ProtectKeysWithDpapi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection.dataprotectionbuilderextensions.protectkeyswithdpapi?view=aspnetcore-3.1) (make sure to use the same windows user to unprotect the key)
- [ProtectKeysWithDpapiNG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.dataprotection.dataprotectionbuilderextensions.protectkeyswithdpaping?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

Your example could for instance be extended with `ProtectKeysWithDpapi()` like this:

```
services
.AddDataProtection()
...
.PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\MyDir"))
.ProtectKeysWithDpapi();
```